# How do you make a background image full screen?

Tags: html, css

Okay I'm building a web page but the border is stopping the background from being full-screen how do i correct this? this is my code set up could you figure out where i went wrong i'm using html as a base.

Comment: Hi, Googling `html fullscreen background` should get you started. If you get stuck with *that*, you're welcome to ask a more specific question, but this is too broad I'm afraid...

Comment: Please tag your questions with a little more sense in the future. This has nothing to do with `codeigniter`, but concerns HTML and CSS. (Tags changed.)

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: no code.... what you want us to do?

Comment: sorry i couldn't find the right tag hopefully i'll have a better grasp of it and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this????

```css
.test{
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/800/400/cats');
  background-size:cover;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

Comment: thank you this is something i was looking for if i knew how to post my own code i would've added it to show my problem.